# Why does Carnot Engine have the curves as isothermal and adiabatic?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why exactly does the Carnot engine have two isothermal and two adiabatic curves? (My book says that “a process is quasi-static if the temperature difference between the system and the reservoir is infinitesimal. Hence it is isothermal. For the connecting two isotherms ;only reversible adiabatic is suitable. If(say) it were isochoric then we shall need a series of reservoirs in the temperature range defined by the two reservoir and the sink” .I don’t get it. Please help.

Comment: To maximize the efficiency of a heat engine, you need to have work done by the engine to be maximum, whereas the heat input to be minimum. If you considering two heat reservoirs between which the engine is operating, you need to have isothermal processes, as the temperature doesn't change, but to satisfy the above mentioned criterion, you will find out that adiabetic processes are the best ones as there is no heat input, but still the engine does work. If you consider any other process instead of adiabetic process, you can't maximise the ratio of work done to heat input to the engine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about chemistry. The carnot engine is a set of physical processes.

Comment: Well then you may as well be in favour of shutting thermodynamics out of chemistry.

Comment: @Jan I think the question might be homework, but I disagree with closing the question on the grounds that it is about physics. The OP has a point that it would seem to say that much of thermodynamics such be off-topic. On the other hand, I agree that the OP might get a better answer to this on Physis SE (once they add a little more of their own thoughts on the problem they are having)

Comment: @Tyberius Not *all* of thermodynamics but I do see the extreme end as being practically physics only. Not that I come from pretty much the opposite side of the spectrum being an organic chemist.

Comment: @Jan I think the line between the two is blurring more as time goes on. I would agree this is probably closer to physics than chemistry, but its a very commonly covered topic in chemical thermodynamics courses. For a lot of physical chemistry, you do have to make detours through topics that are almost entirely just physics or math to make sense of certain useful concepts (e.g. isotherms, adiabatic, engines, and heat sinks)

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a Carnot cycle is comprised of 2 reversible isotherms and 2 reversible adiabats.

Regarding your question about isochoric heating or cooling, if you are going to carry this out reversibly, then you can't do it with just one constant temperature reservoir.  For the heating or cooling to be reversible, the temperature difference between the system and the reservoir(s) must be tiny over the entire path.  To do this, you need a sequence of constant temperature reservoirs running from the starting temperature to the ending temperature.  After the system has equilibrated with each reservoir in the sequence, you move on to the next reservoir.  That way, the temperature difference between the system and the reservoir is tiny along each step of the process path.

Comment: I think I meant why would it be that only those specific curves imply maximum efficiency for which the Carnot cycle is known for?

Comment: You can represent any reversible cycle as a superposition of mini Carnot cycles.  A diagram of this is in virtually every thermodynamics book. The mini Carnot cycles have different temperature extremes, so each of the mini cycles has its own efficiency.  The overall efficiency you the cycle is a weighted average of these mini-cycle efficiencies.  But it will be less than the efficiency calculated from the pair of most extreme temperatures.